# Include date in nginx log file name

Tags: nginx

I am running nginx 1.15.6 and I am trying to include the current date in the nginx log file name.

Some thing like this: access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.2018.11.07.log  main;

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You intend to make log rotating automatically without extra scripts?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I ended up using and it works perfectly:

```
map $time_iso8601 $year {
    default '0000';
    "~^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})" $1;
}
map $time_iso8601 $month {
    default '00';
    "~^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})" $2;
}
map $time_iso8601 $day {
    default '00';
    "~^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})" $3;
}

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.$year-$month-$day.log  apm_json;
```

Comment: Perfect! Works fine here!

Comment: What happens if we drop the `default` section?

Answer (score 1):

```
server {

    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/$year-$month-$day-access.log;
```

Answer (score 0):

IF is Evil, in Nginx configurations. A detailed description as to why can be found at [Nginx: If is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

A better solution would be to use a map for logging dates.

Example below.

```
map $time_iso8601 $year {
    default             'date';
    '~^(?<yyyy>\d{4})-'     $yyyy;
}
map $time_iso8601 $month {
    default             'not';
    '~^\d{4}-(?<mm>\d{2})-'     $mm;
}
map $time_iso8601 $day {
    default             'found';
    '~^\d{4}-\d{2}-(?<dd>\d{2})'    $dd;
}
map $time_iso8601 $logfile_date {
    default                         'date-not-found';
    '~^(?<year>\d{4})-(?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2})'    $year-$month-$day;
}

access_log c:/tools/nginx/logs/$logfile_date.access.log;
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation why `if` is evil? That will help readers make a more informed choice which solution to chose. Thanks!

Comment: In this instance, the  if statement may not execute when the HTTP request is malformed, resulting in an invalid file name and an additional set of records in the error log, nginx complaining about undefined variables. I found this rabbit hole by analysing logs in my Elastic Beanstalk app. AWS docs direct admins to use `if` to set the log file name for enhanced health check, which I did. My app then got scanned with https://github.com/neex/phuip-fpizdam, which was sending malformed requests, consequently triggering the errors I talked about. See https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,255226,255238

Comment: I came upon this thread, having the same issue. The solution does not work for me (nginx 1.20 alpine), I can use logfile_date inside log lines but when I try to use it as part of the access log file name, the file simply doesn't get created and nothing is written in the nginx error log, it simply gets ignored. If I remove the $logfile_date part from the name, logs work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I use crontab to run a shell script every 0h 1m.

**Structure of the form:**

```
~/home/
    log/
        nginx/
            access/
                2023-10-03.log
                2023-10-02.log
                2023-10-01.log
                ...
            errors/
                2023-10-03.log
                2023-10-02.log
                2023-10-01.log
                ...
```

**Concept:** Create a config file with the date, then include the config file in the server block of domain config

**Domain config in /etc/nginx/conf.d**

```
server {    
    listen 80;
    include /etc/nginx/log_by_date.conf;    
    root /.../;
...
}
```

**Shell script update_log_by_date.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash
date=$(date -Id)
home_folder="/home"
nginx_logs="$home_folder/logs/nginx"

# Create log folder if it does not exist
mkdir -p "$nginx_logs/access"
mkdir -p "$nginx_logs/errors"

# Create log file if does not exist
accessFile="$nginx_logs/access/${date}.log"
test -f $accessFile || touch $accessFile

errorFile="$nginx_logs/errors/${date}.log"
test -f $errorFile || touch $errorFile

# Set permission
chown -R nginx:nginx $nginx_logs

# Overwrite config
echo "access_log $nginx_logs/access/${date}.log;" > $home_folder/log_by_date.conf
echo "error_log $nginx_logs/errors/${date}.log warn;" >> $home_folder/log_by_date.conf

# Copy config file to nginx folder
sudo cp $home_folder/log_by_date.conf /etc/nginx

# Restart nginx to update config
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Use crontab to run the script everyday at 0h1m
`1 0 * * * sh /folder/update_log_by_date.sh`