# Nginx Access Log Automatic rotation

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Hi I'm trying to apply a log rotation in Nginx access log by adding the date in the file name that will be then processed by logorate.d.

I applied the same (or similar ) configuration that i found here:
https://www.cambus.net/log-rotation-directly-within-nginx-configuration-file/

or the solution proposed in this SO thread:

[Include date in nginx log file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53196478/include-date-in-nginx-log-file-name)

My last attempt is with this configuration:

```
http{
.....
 map $time_iso8601 $year {
    default             'date';
    '~^(?<yyyy>\d{4})-'     $yyyy;
    }
    map $time_iso8601 $month {
        default             'not';
        '~^\d{4}-(?<mm>\d{2})-'     $mm;
    }
    map $time_iso8601 $day {
        default             'found';
        '~^\d{4}-\d{2}-(?<dd>\d{2})'    $dd;
    }
    map $time_iso8601 $logfile_date {
        default                         'date-not-found';
        '~^(?<year>\d{4})-(?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2})'    $year-$month-$day;
    }


    access_log /var/log/nginx/access-$logfile_date.log main;


....
}
```

There is no error and nginx start and works just fine but the access log is not created.

Using simple names like access.log or accesstest.log works and the log is created and updated.

I'm running nginx via podman containers on a Centos and the base image is nginx:1.15.12-alpine

From the test I did seems that I'm not able to use a variable as part of the name, for example I did try using $host as part of the name (access-$host.log) and the file was not created as well. 
Anyone has an idea of what could be the problem?.

**UPDATE**
I did change the docker image to see if was a problem related to the image i use and I did try the tag image:  1.17.3-alpine-perl , but without luck.

Comment: Question is why you need this and what's wrong with default logrotate configuration of NGINX?

Comment: Can you explain a bit the default logroation ? Maybe i missed something that was already there form the Nginx default configuration I did not got the idea that the log could be rotate to a new file "automatically"  I saw the same access for "days" .
Anyway the need is as well to have it on daily base and easily identify the log by name in case of debug.

Comment: It depends on your particular Linux distro package. How did you instal nginx ?

Comment: it runs via docker image on an official image : nginx:1.15.12-alpine . I did not install it on the Centos.